# error: unable to find string literal operator "" SLASHES

Tags: c++, qt, gcc4

I'm trying to build qtCreator 2.3 with gcc 4.7 and I'm getting following error:

> error: unable to find string literal operator ""

I'm using `mingw32-make -lto` as qtCreator source dir. Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by "SLASHES"? Is there more to the error than you're showing here?

Answer (score 28):

Just Googled this and saw the following comment on [this page](http://groups.google.com/group/cython-users/browse_thread/thread/d0262ac367111658?pli=1)

> The subject error occurs because in the new c++11 a space between string concatenation is mandatory

It may be related to what you're seeing.

Comment: apparently this is legal: `#define TEST(Name) "TEST" Name"TEST"` but this is not: `#define TEST(Name) "TEST"Name"TEST"`, so you have to have a space after the literal, but not before?!  Oh well... Thanks, that fixed my problem!